# What are all the ways that FPGAs are used in the Flying Laptop spacecraft?

Tags: flight-computer, computing, data-systems

In the eoPortal's spacecraft Mission profile for the [Flying Laptop](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/f/flying-laptop), the term FPGA ([Field Programmable Gate Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array)) appears 12 times, including the paragraph below. I'm still having trouble understanding how many FPGAs are used *in toto* and what precisely is each of their functions. Could someone more fluent in spacecraft computer systems architecture help clarify this?

> FPGAs: The introduction and reliance of onboard computing with an FPGA system represents a new approach to conventional system architectures. It provides the capability to directly generate the logical configuration of FPGA gates from a C-like high level language without producing the machine code for a processor (hence, massive parallel processing is possible). Using an onboard computer architecture with several reciprocative checking FPGAs, a safe system is obtained that even exceeds the performance of current PCs through its ability of parallel real-time processing. An inherent advantage of FPGA architectures is the capability of reconfiguration within milliseconds.

I've taken the time to [profile some of the specifications and innovations of the Flying Laptop](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22515/12102).

Also see the question [How do Field Programmable Gate Arrays affect the capabilities of probes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9555/12102)

---

**EDIT:** I had a false start when I was reading about the [LEON 3 FT processor core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEON#LEON3FT_processor_core). According to Wikipedia:

> An FPGA implementation called LEON3FT-RTAX is proposed for critical space applications.

However, *I don't think* that the FPGA implementation is used here; The [UT 699 LEON 3 FT](http://mil-embedded.com/eletter-products/aeroflex-your-one-stop-source-to-create-your-custom-leon-3ft-microprocessor/) is an [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) implementation.

Comment: FPGAs on spacecraft are hardly new.

Comment: @pericynthion this [excellent answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9561/12102) details numerous instances of "FPGAs on spacecraft". However the quote above refers to the use of FPGAs in "PCs" and "conventional systems" and does not tout the novelty of the appearance of FPGAs in spacecraft in any way. So is your comment really just a snarky *[non sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic))?*

Comment: @pericynthion if there is a *conventional satellite system architecture* that *relies on FPGA computing*, an example would be appreciated. I'd call Mars rovers *unconventional* and the use of FPGAs in spacecraft *highly application specific*. A good counterexample is most welcome.

Comment: They weren't new when I built two of them into every one of the ~180 Planet Labs cubesats.  My comment isn't a non sequitur, it's pointing out the fatuous nature of your source's assertion that use of FPGAs is a new approach.

Comment: @pericynthion I like to think of Planet Labs' approach as truly *unconventional*, new and innovative. But if you'd like to assert here that the Dove design is an example of FPGA use in a *conventional system architecture*, that's your prerogative.

Comment: Do you really mean "Floating Point Gate Array"?  Most satellites use "Field Programmable Gate Array"

Comment: @asdfex thanks! I'll update the link now. While I've been [thinking about the use of an FPGA to do *Floating Point* calculations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/317525/102305) for a recreation of the first visualization of the Mandelbrot set (also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2358889/284619)), FP indeed stands for "Field Programmable".

Comment: FPGA is just a convenient way to implementing digital circuits without the need to set up a factory and mass production to average down the unit cost. Almost all custom design and low volume products are implemented as FPGA. Also the collection of space grade ICs are quite limited compared with commercial or industrial grade, so it could be easier to source the design and flash it into a space grade FPGA than constraining the design into the IC catalog.

Comment: @user3528438 that's certainly one important use use, but is "is just a" under-representing the full range of applications that FPGA's address? Are you sure that their ability to be *quickly and dynamically reconfigured and optimized during use* is never exploited, especially in space applications?

Comment: @user3528438 reconfigurable FPGA used in a space telescope mentioned here for example: [What are the general properties and specs for JWST's onboard data and image processing capabilities?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43768/12102)

Comment: using an FPGA implementation of a processor